# Same Expected Value but different variances. Is $E[U(X)] \ge E[U(Y)]$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, economics

Let $U: \mathbb R -> \mathbb R$ be a concave function, and let $X$ be a random variable with a normal distribution, expected value $\mu$, and standard deviation $\sigma$. Let $\lambda \gt 1$, and let $Y$ be a random variable with a normal distribution, expected value $\mu$, and standard deviation $\mu \sigma$.

(a)Prove that $U(\mu + c) + U(\mu-c) \ge U(\mu + c\sqrt{\lambda}) + U(\mu - c\sqrt{\lambda})$ for all $c \gt 0$

(b) By changing appropriate varible, and using a), prove that $E[U(X)] \ge E[U(Y)]$

I can only know Jensen's inequality which is $U[E(X)] \ge E[U(X)]$. I have no idea how to prove a) and b). Can you please help me? I have forgone statistics for a long time so I greatly appreciate for your help. Thanks.

Comment: For $Y$, do you mean its standard deviation is $\lambda \sigma$?

Comment: This follows directly from your previous question since $Y$ is distributed as $X+Z$ where $Z$ is independent of $X$ and centered normal with variance $(\lambda-1)\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Michael yes, it is Mr.Michael. I still do not understand what I can do by drawing a picture for question a). Is there any possibility to prove rigorously? Also, since U(.) is concave, your generalization does not work. I THANK YOU A LOT FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: @michael yes, the computation seems very legitimate.

Comment: When I said "draw a picture" it was to get inspiration for a proof that you can then do rigorously if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) I think you have some typos in the question. Let us make things more clear by assuming $Y$ has standard deviation $\left(\sqrt{\lambda}\right) \sigma$.

1) Draw a picture and compare the midpoints of the two line segments.

2) Define "centered densities":

\begin{align}
\tilde{f}_X(x) &= f_X(x+\mu)\\
\tilde{f}_Y(x) &= f_Y(x + \mu) 
\end{align} 
Note that $\tilde{f}_X(c)=\tilde{f}_X(-c)$ and $\tilde{f}_Y(c) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\tilde{f}_X\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.  I think this problem wants you to do the computation:

\begin{align} 
E[U(X)] &= \int_{c=0}^{\infty} U(\mu+c)\tilde{f}_X(c)dc + \int_{c=0}^{\infty} U(\mu-c)\tilde{f}_X(-c)dc\\
&= \int_{c=0}^{\infty} \tilde{f}_X(c)[U(\mu+c)+U(\mu-c)]dc\\
&\geq \ldots
\end{align}

---

A more general statement that does not require the density of $X$ to be symmetric about the mean is this:

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Let $X$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $E[X]=0$ and let $Y=\theta X$ for some $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Claim:  $E[g(Y)]\leq E[g(X)]$.

Proof:  Define the convex function $h(x) = g(x)-g(0)$.  Then $h(0)=0$ and we have: 
\begin{align}
E[h(Y)] &= E[h(\theta X)]\\
&= E[h(\theta X + (1-\theta)0)]\\
&\leq E[\theta h(X) + (1-\theta)h(0)]\\
&=\theta E[h(X)]
\end{align} 
However, $E[h(X)] \geq h(E[X])=h(0)=0$, and so $\theta E[h(X)]\leq E[h(X)]$. It follows that $E[h(Y)]\leq E[h(X)]$. Thus: 
$$ E[g(Y)-g(0)] \leq E[g(X)-g(0)]$$
$\Box$

Comment: The same claim of course holds if "$Y=\theta X$" is replaced with "$Y \overset{d}{=}\theta X$", meaning equality in distribution.

Comment: You can remove the zero-mean assumption by appropriately centering:  If $Y-E[X] \overset{d}{=}\theta (X-E[X])$ with $\theta \in [0,1]$, then $E[g(Y)] \leq E[g(X)]$ for any convex function $g:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  This follows from the above claim by defining $R=Y-E[X]$, $S=X-E[X]$, so $R=\theta S$, and applying the claim to the convex function $g(x+E[X])$.